# Python selecting elements in a list by indices

Tags: python, list, indexing, set

I have a list in python that I want to get the a set of indexes out of and save as a subset of the original list:

```
templist = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]]
```

and I want this:

```
   sublist=[[1,    4,    7,                      16,      19,20]]
```

as an example.

I have no way of knowing ahead of time what the contents of the list elements will be .  All I have is the indices that will always be the same.

Is there a single line way of doing this?

Comment: how are the indices stored?

Comment: What do you mean?  Python give each element in a list it's own index?

Comment: so tell me if i understood this correctly: you have a list, you have some indices and you want to extract a sub list which contains elements of the list at those indices.

Comment: yes sir.  They are scattered all over the index, so I'm suspicious that the `:` operator won't work since that does consecutive element selection

Comment: so how do you know which indices in the list to select?

Comment: are the indices always the same? I.e do you know that you will always want elements at indices 1,4,7,16,19,20 only? or can the indices vary too?

Comment: The process I'm using to generate the list also records a lot of uninteresting data that I don't care about.  I only want to keep a few things of interest from what my process outputs, and it's output structure is the same every time.

Comment: the indices are always the same...they never vary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you know what the indices to be selected are, it would work something like this:

```
indices = [1, 4, 7, 16, 19, 20]
templist = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21]]
sublist = []

for i in indices:
    sublist.append(templist[0][i])
```

This can also be expressed in the form of a list comprehension -

```
sublist = [templist[0][i] for i in indices]
```

Answer (score 6):

Using [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
>>> templist = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]]
>>> import operator
>>> f = operator.itemgetter(0,3,6,15,18,19)
>>> sublist = [list(f(templist[0]))]
>>> sublist
[[1, 4, 7, 16, 19, 20]]
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use list comprehension with enumerate:

```
indices = [1,2,3]
sublist = [element for i, element in enumerate(templist) if i in indices]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 mylist = ['A','B','C','D','E','F']
 idx = [0,1,3]
 [mylist[i] for i in idx]
```

['A', 'B', 'D']

Comment: That doesn't answer OP's question at all, was this supposed to be another question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension:

```
indices = set([1,2,3])
sublist = [el for i, el in enumerate(orig_list) if i in indices]
```

Or you can store indices in a list of True/False and use `itertools.compress`:

```
indices = [True, False, True]
sublist = itertools.compress(orig_list, indices)
```