# Python Iterating on list using another list

Tags: python, arrays, list

I think it is simple but it isn't working with me.
I have 2 lists:

```
a = [1, 3, 6]
b = [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'],
     ['H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N'],
     ['O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U']]
```

and I need to iterate over b using a's elements.

The desired output is:

```py
c = [['B', 'D', 'G'],
     ['I', 'K', 'N'],
     ['P', 'R', 'U']]
```

Arrays are welcome, Any suggestions?

Comment: why `a` has 3 elems and your wished output inner list 4?

Comment: please describe more how your algorithm should work.

Comment: Duplicate of [Python selecting elements in a list by indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23763591/python-selecting-elements-in-a-list-by-indices) & [Access multiple elements of list knowing their index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18272160/access-multiple-elements-of-list-knowing-their-index)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html?highlight=itemgetter#operator.itemgetter) method from the built in [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) module:

```
from operator import itemgetter

a = itemgetter(1, 3, 6)

b = [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'],
     ['H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N'],
     ['O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U']]

c = [list(a(l)) for l in b]

print(c)
```

Output:

```
[['B', 'D', 'G'],
 ['I', 'K', 'N'],
 ['P', 'R', 'U']]
```

Answer (score 1):

If `a` is supposed to index into each sublist you could use the following nested list comprehension

```
>>> [[sub[i] for i in a] for sub in b]
[['B', 'D', 'G'],
 ['I', 'K', 'N'],
 ['P', 'R', 'U']]
```

If `a` and `b` were `numpy.array` could also do

```
>>> b[:, a]
array([['B', 'D', 'G'],
       ['I', 'K', 'N'],
       ['P', 'R', 'U']], dtype='<U1')
```

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming that the expected output just has a typo.)

The most efficient generic way is through [`operator.itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter).

```
from operator import itemgetter


a = [1, 3, 6]

b = [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'],
     ['H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N'],
     ['O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U']]

c = [list(itemgetter(*a)(x)) for x in b]
print(c)
# [['B', 'D', 'G'], ['I', 'K', 'N'], ['P', 'R', 'U']]
```

For your input sizes, the conversion to `list` brings it actually on par with a double list comprehension on my system, but it is otherwise faster. For larger `a` sizes, NumPy gets to actually be the fastest (although it requires the inner lists of `b` to have the same number of elements, which `itemgetter` does not care about).

Some timings as they come out from my test system:

```
%timeit [[x[i] for i in a] for x in b]
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.14 µs per loop
%timeit [list(itemgetter(*a)(x)) for x in b]
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.13 ns per loop
%timeit [itemgetter(*a)(x) for x in b]
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 732 ns per loop
%timeit np.array(b)[:, tuple(a)]
# 100000 loops, best of 3: 6.84 µs per loop

b = b * 1000000
%timeit [[x[i] for i in a] for x in b]
# 1 loop, best of 3: 1.19 s per loop
%timeit [list(itemgetter(*a)(x)) for x in b]
# 1 loop, best of 3: 1.15 s per loop
%timeit [itemgetter(*a)(x) for x in b]
# 1 loop, best of 3: 800 ms per loop
%timeit np.array(b)[:, tuple(a)]
# 1 loop, best of 3: 2.31 s per loop

a = a * 100
b = b * 10000
%timeit [[x[i] for i in a] for x in b]
# 1 loop, best of 3: 386 ms per loop
%timeit [list(itemgetter(*a)(x)) for x in b]
# 10 loops, best of 3: 193 ms per loop
%timeit [itemgetter(*a)(x) for x in b]
# 10 loops, best of 3: 171 ms per loop
%timeit np.array(b)[:, tuple(a)]
# 10 loops, best of 3: 63.1 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

I like to use `map` to make operations on lists:

```
list(map(lambda x: [x[i] for i in a], b))
```

```
[['B', 'D', 'G'], ['I', 'K', 'N'], ['P', 'R', 'U']]
```

Answer (score 1):

For its shortness, semantics and doing without additional modules I'd prefer a nested list comprehension:

```
>>> [[l[i] for i in a] for l in b]
[['B', 'D', 'G'], ['I', 'K', 'N'], ['P', 'R', 'U']]
```

The outer comprehension means 'create a list and add the inner comprehension's result for every list `l` in `b` to it.' The inner comprehension says 'create a list and add the `i`-th element of `l` for every `i` in `a` to it.'

I noticed that @norok2 tested how fast this option is, but didn't present it explicitly.